# Send to polaroid printer from java

Tags: java, printing

I have a java application which creates polaroids from particular images and sends to a polaroid printer (Canon SELPHY). However when I specify the custom media size to be printed it gives me a *java.lang.RuntimeException: No printer services available.* The code for the printing is below:

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
pras.add(new Copies(1));
pras.add(new MediaPrintableArea(0, 0, 86, 54, MediaPrintableArea.MM));
PrintService pss[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF, pras);
```

The initial problem here is pss[] is not populated. When no media size is specified I simply get an error from the printer basically saying the media size is not supported.

Does anyone have any experience in this area which can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom media sizes **MUST** be supported and usually **DEFINED** by your printer (i.e. **printer driver**) and **printing subsystem** (e.g. CUPS in Linux). You might want to check that your media size is really correctly configured (see the code bellow).

**More importantly** - Java Printing API **REQUIRES** media to be defined and handled in **PORTRAIT** orientation! You are **incorrectly** entering printable area in landscape (`width > height`). The orientation of the actual printing is controlled by `OrientationRequested` print request attribute a bit later.

---

If you want to check printers and supported media sizes recognized by Java Printing API, you can use the following code:

```
public class MediaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(
                DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE, null);
        for (PrintService printService : printServices) {
            System.out.println(printService.getName());
            Media[] supportedMedia = (Media[]) printService.getSupportedAttributeValues(
                    Media.class, DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE, null);
            for (Media media : supportedMedia) {
                if (media instanceof MediaSizeName) {
                    handleMediaSizeName((MediaSizeName) media);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void handleMediaSizeName(MediaSizeName mediaSizeName) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("    " + mediaSizeName.toString());
        MediaSize mediaSize = MediaSize.getMediaSizeForName(mediaSizeName);
        if (mediaSize != null) {
            float[] size = mediaSize.getSize(MediaSize.MM);
            builder.append(" - ").append(size[0]).append("x").append(size[1]).append("mm");
        }
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay so as expected I got the _Card size 86x54mm - 54.0x86.0mm_, however changing to floats and portrait still has the same issue.

Comment: Try to change `DocFlavor` to `DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE` so that we can be sure it is caused by the media size and not the doc flavor.

Comment: Sadly this does not change anything. Thanks for your help so far BTW.

Comment: Ok... so - forget about trying to get *printer service* by specifying *printable area*. Just get all the *printer services* (aka printers), pick the one you want (e.g. based on its name), then request supported media sizes and pick the one you want (just like in the example code above) and then simply print using the found media.

Comment: Top man! However the polaroid is now printed the wrong way around. I'm sure I can sort that, cheers!